# What does it mean to show that an integral exists?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, terminology

**Question**

I am slightly unclear on some terminology that I have come across in the following question:

- *Let $f(x, t) = xe^{−xt}$ Show that the integral $I(x) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x, t)\ dt $ **exists** for all $x ≥ 0$.*

What does it mean to show that an integral exists? Does this simply mean to show that it converges? I looked this up for some clarification but could only find questions rather than a precise description of what this means.

I would be grateful for any explanation.

Comment: Yes, it means that it converges.

Comment: Definite integral is a number; $I(x)$ is a function of $x$: thus, we have to verify that for every non-negative value of $x$ the function $I(x)$ is defined, i.e. has a value.

Comment: This can be usually easily verified by context. What book is this exercise from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (improper Riemann) integral $\int \limits_0^{\infty} g(t) \, \text{d} t$ is said to exist if:

1. For each $a > 0$ the proper Riemann integral $\int \limits_0^a g(t) \, \text{d} t$ exists, i.e. $g$ is Riemann integrable over $[0, a]$;
2. The limit $\lim \limits_{a \to \infty} \int \limits_0^a g(t) \, \text{d} t$ exists.

The integral $\int \limits_0^{\infty} g(t) \, \text{d} t$ is then the value of the limit. Now for your question just apply the definition to $g(t) := f(x, t)$, where $x \geqslant 0$ is fixed.

Comment: Yours is an important point to make here I think.  All too often posters will bring up the Lebesgue integral when the OP quite clearly by his question and by his earlier questions must be interpreting this as an improper Riemann integral.   When the integrand is continuous it seems weird to raise the issue of "measurability."  The two integrals (Lebesgue and improper Riemann) on $[0,\infty)$ are compatible but very distinct: either can exist with the other failing to exist.

Answer (score 2):

The question is about if the mapping $\displaystyle x\mapsto \int_{0}^{+\infty}xe^{-xt}\, {\rm d}t$ exists over the interval $[0,+\infty]$. So we can answer two question:

- Does it exists if $x=0$?
- Does it exists if $x>0$?

If the answer is "yes" in both cases, then the mapping exists over the interval $[0,+\infty]$.

Well,

- If $x=0$, so $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}0e^{-0\cdot t}\, {\rm d}t=0$ so there exists and equals to the mapping zero.
- If $x>0$, so $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}xe^{-xt}\, {\rm d}t=x\lim_{b\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{b}e^{-xt}\, {\rm d}t=x\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1$ so there exists and equals to the mapping one.

Therefore since both cases the answer is "yes" we can say: the mapping $\displaystyle x\mapsto \int_{0}^{+\infty}xe^{-xt}\, {\rm d}t$ exists over all $[0,+\infty]$" and converges to the function $I(x)={\bf 1}_{\{x>0\}}$ or strictly saying to $\displaystyle x\mapsto \begin{cases} 1, \quad \text{if}\quad x\in [0,+\infty]\\ 0,\quad \text{if}\quad x=0\end{cases}$

Comment: I think the integral should be over dt and not dx in the first line.

Comment: @WaterMolecule thank you, I fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

The integral exists as an element of $[0, \infty]$ because the integrand is nonnegative and measurable. But sometimes people use "$\int f$ exists" to mean that $\int |f| < \infty$. At other times, people use "$\int f$ exists" to mean that some kind of problem specific limit exists. For example, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ does not exist in the first sense, but does exist in the second sense.

Comment: That is of course true if you are talking about the Lebesgue integral. For the Riemann integral positivity is in general not enough.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes; even for the Lebesgue integral we need measurability of $f$.